# Android Studio 3.2 for Windows wrong repository

Tags: android, android-studio

today I tried to install Android Studio 3.2 in Windows 10 and I received a lot of errors. When I tried to correct I observed that download is getting WRONG MACOSX sdk and tools. Anyone know how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually download SDK for Windows here and extract it: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip

Then you go to Android Studio settings and point Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK to extracted folder.